# Why threads count is increased by more than one when queuing to ThreadPool by calling Task.Run and ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, threadpool

I was trying to figure out running threads count in console application with the help of that `Thread`:

```
new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                Console.WriteLine(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count);
            }
        }).Start();
```

And after that I have started new `Thread` which contains very simple logic to execute. And without any surprise threads count is increased by `1`. For `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` it is increased by 3.

And did same test for `Task.Run(() => {...})`. And surprisingly threads count is increased by `4` or sometimes `5`. And unfortunately, I can not understand the reason.

Here is the full code for testing:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    new Thread(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            Console.WriteLine(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count);
        }
    }).Start();

    //Task.Run(() =>
    //{
    //    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    //}); // thread count is 12

    //new TaskFactory().StartNew(() =>
    //{
    //    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    //}); // thread count is 12

    //ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((onj) =>
    //{
    //    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    //}); // thread count is 9

    //new Thread(() =>
    //{       
    //    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    //}).Start(); // thread count is 7

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

My question is that, why running new Task increases thread count by 4 or 5? And why queuing work item for the thread pool increases thread count by 3?

Comment: Note that `Task.Run` posts work to the ThreadPool - it doesn't spin up a new thread

Comment: use System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count in the task too since Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId is not the count.

Comment: @canton7 Yes, I know. Just like `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` as well

Comment: @Fredou For getting count I have dedicated thread which I shared with you in the first lines of my question

Comment: One of the main points of working with `Task` and `Task<T>` is to focus on the *work at hand*, not on the *mechanism*. Why do you care so much about how many threads the *runtime* happens to have running at any particular time?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I was comparing running threads count of two different implementations. Because, as less running threads then less context switching and so on. And wasn't able to find out why count is increased so. Then, I wrote  that simple code to find out the differences. I beleiveit is documented somewhere, but I have no any luck to find it

Comment: Note that just because a thread appears in `GetCurrentProcess().Threads`, doesn't mean it's *running*. It's probably a ThreadPool that's not doing anything.

Comment: @canton7 All your words are understandable. But, why it is not so for `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`? Also, I just searched a lot to find exact reason and wasn't able to find. That's why asked in SO.

Comment: `Task.Run` should have exactly the same behaviour as `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` (strictly, `ThreadPool.UnsafeQueueUserWorkItem`): `Task.Run` calls this under the hood. If you're seeing differences, they're probably differences caused by some other unrelated factors. I was responding to your "*as less running threads then less context switching and so on*", pointing out that the threads you're looking at *aren't* necessarily running: have a look at each thread's `ThreadState`.

Comment: Note that you're asking about the internals of ThreadPool behaviour, which are relatively poorly understood outside of Microsoft, so it's not surprising that you're struggling to find answers.

Comment: @canton7 We are on the same road. I will just wait a bit, and then may be will delete answer. I thought that may be I am overlooking some details.

Comment: The sleep is too long, it inspires the threadpool manager to add more threads to the pool.  "Too long" is half a second.  Code that needs more than ~three billion processor instructions to get the job done is usually bogged-down by something that doesn't involve executing code.  Usually blocking, waiting for I/O completion being the typical case.  Adding more threads is then warranted to try to get locks released and get more real work done.

Comment: @HansPassant Your thoughts seems meaningful. But, I see no difference after deleting sleep call from actions. If possible, could you please write answer with more detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The threadpool employs a [complicated mechanism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2010/september/concurrency-throttling-concurrency-in-the-clr-4-0-threadpool) to determine how many threads will be running.

When you queue work to the threadpool by calling `QueueUserItem` or creating a `Task`, the threadpool gets initialized with a default initial number of threads, that is usually four.

Comment: Could you please share the documentation which has such note about default initial number of threads in thread pool?

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev you can call the [`ThreadPool.GetMinThreads`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.getminthreads) method to get these values, although the documentation says: *When demand is low, the actual number of thread pool threads can fall below the minimum values*. In my PC is 4 (and 4 I/O completion threads).

Comment: @Nick Thanks for the answer. It overcomes my confusion. Will try to read that article as well.